# How to use many to many relationship in odoo mobile

Tags: android, many-to-many, odoo, odoo-8

I am developing an android application based on Odoo framework. I need to display the Compensatory-Off leaves which is a Many-To-Many field type when ever user selects the leave type called compensatory.

I had tried some code but i am getting error when ever i am binding my Many-To-Many field to the XML:

This is the code i had tried in xml

```
  <odoo.controls.OField
                        android:id="@+id/com_off_ids"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        app:fieldName="compoff_ids"
                        app:fieldTextAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

This is the odoo model of HrHolidays

```
OColumn employee_id = new OColumn("Employee", HrEmployee.class, OColumn.RelationType.ManyToOne);
    OColumn department_id = new OColumn("Department", HrDepartment.class, OColumn.RelationType.ManyToOne);
    OColumn company_id = new OColumn("Company", ResCompany.class, OColumn.RelationType.ManyToOne);
    OColumn holiday_type = new OColumn("Mode", OSelection.class).addSelection("employee", "By Employee").addSelection("category", "By Employee Tag");
    OColumn type = new OColumn("Type", OSelection.class).addSelection("remove", "Remove").addSelection("add", "Add").setDefaultValue("remove");
    @Odoo.Domain("[['line_id', '=', @leave_year_id]]")
    @Odoo.onChange(method = "partnerIdOnChange")
    OColumn holiday_status_id = new OColumn("Leave Type", HrHolidayStatus.class, OColumn.RelationType.ManyToOne);
    OColumn leave_year_id = new OColumn("Leave Year", LeaveYear.class, OColumn.RelationType.ManyToOne);
    OColumn compoff_ids = new OColumn("",CompLeaveRel.class, OColumn.RelationType.ManyToMany).setRelBaseColumn("leave_id").setRelRelationColumn("comp_id").setRelTableName("comp_leave_rel");
```

Here in above code 'Compoff_ids' field is the Many-To-Many Field which i need to store the values.

This is the CompLeaveRel Model fields

```
OColumn name = new OColumn("", OVarchar.class);
OColumn leave_id = new OColumn("", OVarchar.class);
OColumn comp_id = new OColumn("",OVarchar.class);
```

This is the error i am getting when i was binding my OColum to the XML widget:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int odoo.controls.OField$FieldType.ordinal()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int odoo.controls.OField$FieldType.ordinal()' on a null object reference
```

Can any one please tell me How to use and get the data for Many-To-Many Fields in odoo mobile framework.

I had a blocked at here since from past two days

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the column as:

```
OColumn column_name = new OColumn("Description", table_name.class, OColumn.RelationType.ManyToMany);
```

and use the same structure they use in [CRM](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/crm/) app to show a one2many field ([ExpandableListControl](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/crm/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/sale_detail.xml#L135) and it's [Adapter](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/crm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/addons/sale/SalesDetail.java#L158)) or like simple tags.